# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, printing, urllib2, python-import

I found this code to decript PHP, but i guess its and old version, and everytime a different error appears.

will post the original.

```
import urllib
import re

php = urllib.urlopen("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wVs8w44v").read()

# Slight modification below so that we don't escape $
z26 = "jmiO@sxhFnD>J\r/u+RcHz3}g\nd{^8 ?eVwl_T\\\t|N5q)LobU]40!p%,rC-97k<'y=W:P$1BI&S6\"E(K`Y~.Q;f[v2a#X*ZAGtM"

# Decode all $z26[...] strings
for i in range(len(z26)):
    php = php.replace("$z26[" + str(i) + "]", "\"" + z26[i] + "\"")

# Concatenate decoded strings
php = php.replace("\".\"", "")

# Replace all $GLOBALS[...]
globals = {}
for m in re.finditer("\$GLOBALS\['(?P<key>\w+?)'\] = \"(?P<value>.*?)\";", php):
    globals[m.group("key")] = m.group("value")
php = re.sub(" \$GLOBALS\['(?P<key>\w+?)'\] = \"(?P<value>.*?)\";", "", php)
for key in globals.keys():
    php = php.replace("$GLOBALS['" + key + "']", globals[key])

print php
```

Well, i made some modifications, but still having problens when Running.

If someone could give a light!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: It has probably nothing to do with your problem, but `globals` is not a very good name for a variable: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals